# Android Java get if minimized

Tags: java, android, onpause

Is there anyway to check if the application is minimized or if you have locked your device?
Because when I do minimize / lock my device the application is still runnig, this is mainly because I'd like to pause the music / sfx not to annoy people.. Like if someone is calling.

I am using Activity and SurfaceView with threads.

I have tried putting my pause method in the surfaceDestroyed / surfaceChanged but without success.

Comment: Put it in `onPause()` ... http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should understand the activity lifecycle first

[image]

when the activity comes int the foreground it'll enter onPause() and it'll enter onResume if the user returns to the activity, an example to use onPause is like this

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();  // Always call the superclass method first

    // DO YOUR STUFF HERE
    }
}
```

for furthere reference about onPause you can see it here -> [onPause Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html)